# JavaScript Pokémon API. Trying to figure out how to display numbers between 153 and 251, for Pokémon API

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display API Pokemon data for Generation 2 Pokemon only (numbers 153 to 251). I'm self-thought through youtube tutorials so I don't know much about JS math, sorry if my terminology is off.

Im trying to get the "const pokemons_number_johtoDex = "20";" number to basically say show "153 to 251".
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks. :)

```js
const poke_container_johtoDex = document.getElementById('poke_containerjohtoDex');

const pokemons_number_johtoDex = 2;

const colors_johtoDex = {
  fire: '#FDDFDF',
  grass: '#DEFDE0',
  electric: '#FCF7DE',
  water: '#DEF3FD',
  ground: '#f4e7da',
  rock: '#d5d5d4',
  fairy: '#fceaff',
  poison: '#F0D3FF',
  bug: '#f8d5a3',
  dragon: '#97b3e6',
  psychic: '#eaeda1',
  flying: '#F5F5F5',
  fighting: '#E6E0D4',
  normal: '#F5F5F5',
};
const main_types_johtoDex = Object.keys(colors_johtoDex);

const fetchPokemons_johtoDex = async () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= pokemons_number_johtoDex; i++) {
    await getPokemon_johtoDex(i);
  }
};

const getPokemon_johtoDex = async id => {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const pokemon_johtoDex = await res.json();
  createPokemonCard_2(pokemon_johtoDex);
};


function createPokemonCard_2(pokemon_johtoDex) {
  const pokemonEl_johtoDex = document.createElement('div');
  pokemonEl_johtoDex.classList.add('pokemon_2');
  const poke_types_johtoDex = pokemon_johtoDex.types.map(type_johtoDex => type_johtoDex.type.name);
  const type = main_types_johtoDex.find(type_johtoDex => poke_types_johtoDex.indexOf(type_johtoDex) > -1);
  const color_johtoDex = colors_johtoDex[type];

  pokemonEl_johtoDex.style.backgroundColor = color_johtoDex;
  const pokeInnerHTML_johtoDex = `

  <div class="pokeModelContainer container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal${pokemon_johtoDex.id}">
      <div class="pokeiconimage">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vii/icons/${pokemon_johtoDex.id}.png" alt="${name}" />
      </div>
      <div class="pokecardbody">
        <p>No:${pokemon_johtoDex.id} ${name}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal${pokemon_johtoDex.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="pokemonModalContainer">
              <div class="pokemonModalContainerRow">
                <div class="pokemonModelImageDiv col">
                  <img class="pokemonModelImage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/${pokemon_johtoDex.id}.png" alt="${name}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pokeModeltext col">
                  <div class="pokemonModelPokemonName">
                    <h1>${name}</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="poke-text-block">

                    <p class="p">Ability: ${pokemon_johtoDex.abilities[0].ability.name}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="poke-text-block">
                    <p>
                    HP: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[0].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Attack: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[1].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Defense: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[2].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Special-Attack: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[3].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Special-Defense: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[4].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Speed: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[5].base_stat}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="backButton">
                  <p class="p1">back</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> `;

  pokemonEl_johtoDex.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML_johtoDex;
  poke_container_johtoDex.appendChild(pokemonEl_johtoDex);
}


fetchPokemons_johtoDex();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Pokemon API</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
<div class="kanto">
  <p>pokemon display kanto</p>
    <div id="poke_containerjohtoDex" class="poke-container_johtoDex row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; "></div>
</div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you can set the start and end IDs

```
const start_pokemons_number_johtoDex = 153;
const end_pokemons_number_johtoDex = 251;
```

And the change the for to go from start to end defined in those const:

```
  for (let i = start_pokemons_number_johtoDex; i <= end_pokemons_number_johtoDex; i++)
```

This is the complete code:

```js
const poke_container_johtoDex = document.getElementById('poke_containerjohtoDex');

const start_pokemons_number_johtoDex = 153;
const end_pokemons_number_johtoDex = 251;

const colors_johtoDex = {
  fire: '#FDDFDF',
  grass: '#DEFDE0',
  electric: '#FCF7DE',
  water: '#DEF3FD',
  ground: '#f4e7da',
  rock: '#d5d5d4',
  fairy: '#fceaff',
  poison: '#F0D3FF',
  bug: '#f8d5a3',
  dragon: '#97b3e6',
  psychic: '#eaeda1',
  flying: '#F5F5F5',
  fighting: '#E6E0D4',
  normal: '#F5F5F5',
};
const main_types_johtoDex = Object.keys(colors_johtoDex);

const fetchPokemons_johtoDex = async () => {
  for (let i = start_pokemons_number_johtoDex; i <= end_pokemons_number_johtoDex; i++) {
    await getPokemon_johtoDex(i);
  }
};

const getPokemon_johtoDex = async id => {
  const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const pokemon_johtoDex = await res.json();
  createPokemonCard_2(pokemon_johtoDex);
};


function createPokemonCard_2(pokemon_johtoDex) {
  const pokemonEl_johtoDex = document.createElement('div');
  pokemonEl_johtoDex.classList.add('pokemon_2');
  const poke_types_johtoDex = pokemon_johtoDex.types.map(type_johtoDex => type_johtoDex.type.name);
  const type = main_types_johtoDex.find(type_johtoDex => poke_types_johtoDex.indexOf(type_johtoDex) > -1);
  const color_johtoDex = colors_johtoDex[type];

  pokemonEl_johtoDex.style.backgroundColor = color_johtoDex;
  const pokeInnerHTML_johtoDex = `

  <div class="pokeModelContainer container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal${pokemon_johtoDex.id}">
      <div class="pokeiconimage">
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-vii/icons/${pokemon_johtoDex.id}.png" alt="${name}" />
      </div>
      <div class="pokecardbody">
        <p>No:${pokemon_johtoDex.id} ${name}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal${pokemon_johtoDex.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="pokemonModalContainer">
              <div class="pokemonModalContainerRow">
                <div class="pokemonModelImageDiv col">
                  <img class="pokemonModelImage" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-v/black-white/${pokemon_johtoDex.id}.png" alt="${name}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="pokeModeltext col">
                  <div class="pokemonModelPokemonName">
                    <h1>${name}</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="poke-text-block">

                    <p class="p">Ability: ${pokemon_johtoDex.abilities[0].ability.name}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="poke-text-block">
                    <p>
                    HP: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[0].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Attack: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[1].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Defense: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[2].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Special-Attack: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[3].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Special-Defense: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[4].base_stat}<br><br>
                    Speed: ${pokemon_johtoDex.stats[5].base_stat}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="backButton">
                  <p class="p1">back</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> `;

  pokemonEl_johtoDex.innerHTML = pokeInnerHTML_johtoDex;
  poke_container_johtoDex.appendChild(pokemonEl_johtoDex);
}


fetchPokemons_johtoDex();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap');
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Pokemon API</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
<div class="kanto">
  <p>pokemon display kanto</p>
    <div id="poke_containerjohtoDex" class="poke-container_johtoDex row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; "></div>
</div>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
  </main>
</body>
```

I don't know if there is a better way for this API to get a group of IDs in one call, you could look into that in the future.